# Silverlight 4, Ria Services, HttpRequestTimedOutWithoutDetail

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria

I have a database that is being accessed by a Silverlight application. It has an Error_Log in that same database.

I have hundreds of HttpRequestTimedOutWithoutDetail errors in the Error_Log table.  I have set the timeout in the web.config to over a minute.  I often receive the error if I call a query twice in a row.

I've decreased the volume by checking context first, but they still happen often.  At first I thought it was a server load issue, but then I turned up my SQL Server 2008 instance to 3 Gigs of RAM, and I still get it with almost no users.

Can someone please help me understand why these errors happen when seemingly there is no reason to timeout?  Does it have to do with multiple queries being sent at the same time?  Or does it have to do with sending off queries that all hit the same database context?

EDIT:

I'm thinking this might be a connection pooling issue?  I have it turned on, but maybe the connections aren't getting closed properly?

Comment: After simulating a huge amount of SQL server load and never getting this error, I tried testing on several other machines spinning off query after query.  I discovered that it was because the connection of the machine was slow.

Comment: ((WebDomainClient<RealFormsContext.IRealFormsServiceContract>)Context.DomainClient).ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);  

Added this in my App.xaml and testing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((WebDomainClient<RealFormsContext.IRealFormsServiceContract>)Context.DomainClient)
   .ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

That got rid of my Timeout errors.